# Converting ID/Class to String

Tags: jquery

I got the following code on a product sales website.

```
<html>
    <body>

        <div class="descr">
                <div id="productName"></div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

`#productName` is unique to each product (ie. blackTea, whiteTea, greenTea, and so on...)

I'm inserting a div with the id `#productName_description` inside `#productName`. I need a script that grabs the id of `descr:first-child`, adds `"_description"` to the end and applies it to the content I'm trying to load. Essenssially what I'm trying to do is to have an automated script that will do all this without me having to write extra javascript per product:

```
$('#kyoto_matcha').load('https://www.assamteacompany.ca/skin/assam_tea_company/script/product_descriptions.html #kyoto_matcha_description');
```

This is the farthest I've got. After spending hours online looking this question up or trying to figure out a solution I could not figure it out. I keep getting [object Object]_description when outputting it through console.log(). This is the closest I've got:

```
$('.descr:first-child').each(function(){
    var teaAccessory = $('.descr:first-child').attr('id');
    var description = '_description';

    $(this).load('https://www.assamteacompany.ca/skin/assam_tea_company/script/product_descriptions.html #' + teaAccessory + description);
});
```

Comment: The problem is external to the posted code, as `attr('id')` *definitely* returns a string, not an object. Your question about "Converting ID/Class to String" is unanswerable, because they *are* strings already.

Comment: see this : http://jsfiddle.net/QfDv9/

Comment: Okay, so product_descriptions.html contains all the product descriptions, and you're trying to extract them and insert them into your new document?

Comment: I'm trying to import certain divs inside product_descriptions.html within #productName.

Comment: Bartosz, that works great, thanks! But it's replacing #productName with #productName_description rather than inserting it inside.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably write something like this

```
$('.descr').each(function(){
    var teaAccessory = $(this).children().first().attr('id'); // just using $(this).children().attr('id'); should also work
    var description = '_description';

    $(this).load('https://www.assamteacompany.ca/skin/assam_tea_company/script/product_descriptions.html #' + teaAccessory + description);
});
```

I think I understand that you are looking to change the id attribute? This would be the code for that.

```
$('.descr').each(function(){
    $div = $(this).children().first();
    $div.attr('id', $div.attr('id')+'_description');

    $div.load('https://www.assamteacompany.ca/skin/assam_tea_company/script/product_descriptions.html #'+$div.attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but this replaces #productName with #productName_description rather than placing it inside.

Answer (score 0):

Your code would load the same page via ajax for every single occurence of .descr - probably not what you intended.  Also, I've never had much luck with load().  Try this:

```
var url = 'https://www.assamteacompany.ca/skin/assam_tea_company/script/product_descriptions.html';
$.get(url, function(data) {
    var $description = $(data)  // make a jQuery object from the returned data
    $('.descr:first-child').each(function(){
        // construct the ID to search for
        var teaAccessory = $(this).attr('id')+'_description';
        // insert the html from the target page
        $(this).html($(teaAccessory, $description).html())

    });
});
```

Comment: i'm fairly sure that loading the description for each `.descr` is actually OP's intention....